# Why does resistivity not vary due to changes in the length of a conducting wire?

Tags: electrical-resistance

I did an experiment on how the length of a wire affects the resistance and I decided to see whether or not it would also have any effect on the resistivity. I used the equation rho=RA/L and came to the conclusion that there is an inverse relation between the two. Is there some common mistake which people do when doing such calculations? Any ideas and answers are appreciated.

Comment: Note: I realise resisitvity is an intrinsic property. I am just wondering why this happened the way it did.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You said,

$$\rho=\frac{RA}{L}$$

OK, so if you have two wires, that each have the same end-to-end resistance, $R$, and they each have the same cross-sectional area, $A$, but they have different lengths, $L$, then they must be made of materials having different bulk resistivity, $\rho$.

You can compute the bulk resistivity of each from the known resistances, cross-sections, and lengths.

---

> I...came to the conclusion that there is an inverse relation between [$\rho$ and $L$.]

Sounds like you're imagining a *single* piece of wire, and imagining what happens as you vary the length along which the resistance is measured. But if all you do is change the length of a single piece of wire, then it's cross section won't change, and the material from which it is made won't change. Both $\rho$ and $A$ are constants, so if you change $L$, the only other variable that can change is $R$.